# why INNER JOIN errors out at the plus sign?

Tags: inner-join, where-clause, create-view

This is very similar but NOT exactly the same error in an answer I saw for subject "MySQL inner join". The problem is an error at the WHERE statement, as follows: **"ERROR 2.5could not prepare statement (1 no such column: Orders.OrdersID)"**. Are my INNER JOIN statements wrong/Too cheesy?. I have checked each table to ensure fieldnames are correct, nothing works. The Table named ORDERS has the following fields :OrderID   CustomerID   EmployeeID   OrderDate   ShipperID  -- Table named OrderDetails has the following fields: OrderDetailID   OrderID   ProductID   Quantity |||||| Does anyone has an idea or solution for this error?. (It is driving me nuts!!!) . Here is the code:

```
CREATE VIEW OrderView AS 
SELECT Employees.EmployeeID AS 'Employee_EMPLOYEE_ID', 
       Orders.OrderID AS 'Orders_ORDER_ID',
       Orders.EmployeeID AS 'Orders_EMPLOYEE_ID', 
       OrderDetails.OrderID AS 'OrderDetails_ORDER_ID',
       OrderDetails.Quantity AS 'OrderDetails_QTY'
FROM 
       Employees
INNER JOIN Orders ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
INNER JOIN OrderDetails On OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
WHERE OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrdersID
AND   OrderDetails.Quatity > 30
ORDER BY Employees.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: I corrected the statement by changing the tables to be used, the fields to be used, ran it under w3schools and it worked perfectly, as follows:

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the failing set of statements by using different tables, putting all the statements in an indented way, ran in under w3schools and it worked perfectly, as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW OrderView AS
SELECT Orders.OrderID,
       Orders.CustomerID, 
       Customers.CustomerID AS C_CUSTOMERID, 
       Orders.CustomerID AS  O_CUSTOMERID, 
       Orders.ShipperID as O_SHIPPERID, 
       Shippers.ShipperID as S_SHIPPERID, 
       Customers.Country,
       Customers.CustomerName, 
       Shippers.ShipperName
FROM ((Orders
       INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
       INNER JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID)
WHERE Customers.Country='Mexico' or Customers.Country='Germany' or 
      Customers.Country='Spain'
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID
HAVING Customers.CustomerID > 39
ORDER BY Customers.Country ASC;
```